# Is my Universal Windows Platform software able to gain the permission that is necessary for initiation of shutdown?

Tags: c#, uwp, permissions, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I am desiring addition to my Universal Windows Platform software the ability for it to shut-down its host machine after invocation of it by 1 button-click, however, 0 methods that I have tried thus far have operated:

I have attempted to instruct Windows to shut-down, but `shutdown /s /t 120` is not able to operate, specifically after invocation by my application.

Therefore, I attempted uage of native C# code. However, usage of this has informed me that it has not been permitted to invoke `shutdown`:

```cs
ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

I have used many methods, but I am not able to remediate this problem.

## Relevant files

### MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System;
using Windows.System;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409.
// Delete the extra namespaces when the application is complete.

namespace Shutdown_Roulette
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Shutdown, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
        }
    }
}
```

### Package.appxmanifest

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">

  <Identity
    Name="7eb73f1e-b159-4fd0-aab9-4158e57ba08a"
    Publisher="CN=rokeb"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="7eb73f1e-b159-4fd0-aab9-4158e57ba08a" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Shutdown Roulette</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Master Roke Julian Lockhart Beedell</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="Shutdown_Roulette.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="Shutdown Roulette"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="Shutdown Roulette"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png" ShortName="Shutdown Roulette">
        </uap:DefaultTile >
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement"/></Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Please do note that I am wanting to use this command on Windows 10, rather than Windows 10 IoT; I merely am attempting to use those commands because they are the only other way I have been able to conceive of invocation of this without reliance upon either PowerShell, Python or the Windows Command Processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of [ShowdownManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.shutdownmanager), it needs the support of IOT SDK, which means it is a platform-limited API (only valid on IOT devices).

In Windows 10 desktop devices, UWP does not have the permission to turn off the device.